Have an issue with types when creating a Fastify plugin to decorate mongoose models using Zod
I have created a Fastify plugin to decorate Mongoose models, adding them to the Fastify interface:
declare module 'fastify' {
    export interface FastifyInstance {
        models: {
            [key: string]: Model<T>;
        };
        db: Mongoose;
    }
}

I read the directory and load models like this:
const zodObj = (await import(path.resolve(modulesPath, module, `${module}.schema`))).default;

const schema = zodSchema(zodObj.schema);

interface IModel extends z.infer<typeof zodObj.schema>, Document { }

const model: Model<IModel> = connection.model<IModel>(zodObj.name, schema);

if (fastify.hasDecorator('models')) {
    fastify.models = {
        ...fastify.models,
        [module]: model as Model<IModel>
    };
} else {
    fastify.decorate('models', {
        [module]: model as Model<IModel>
    });
}

Here is a sample schema:
import { Document } from "mongoose";
import { z } from "zod";

const schema = z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    email: z.string().email().describe("unique"),
});

export interface IUser extends z.infer<typeof schema>, Document { }

export default {
    name: "User",
    schema,
    relations: [],
};

When I try to access fastify.models.users.find(), it returns the type annotation as any[].
Can anyone help me fix it? I need it to return IModel[] generated from the Zod object instead of any[].
